# Using command line in Fedora to print/echo certain lines in a file

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora

**For Fedora OS**

I'm still learning here, but I need help to insert a command for example "XXX" to say that I have a file that contains 1000 lines of single product names. I need to write a command to basically print specific lines, such as:

print line 50-100 from MyProductList.sh

This is just an example to give you an idea. inside the file will simply be 1000 lines of 1 worded products. One word on each line.

The result I need might look like this:

```
50. tea
51. coffe
52. orange
53. banana
54. etc
```

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Can you edit your question and provide a sample of what the input file will look like?  Is it sorted? Does it have any "gaps" in the numbering, or do the numbers run 1-N?

Comment: Hi Andy, done, I hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Output 5 lines, beginning from line 2:

```
$ tail <infile -n+2 | head -n5 >outfile
```

Output lines 2 to 7:

```
$ tail <infile -n+2 | head -n$((7-2)) >outfile
```

Output lines a to b:

```
$ a=2 ; b=7
$ tail <infile -n+$a | head -n$(($b-$a)) >outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file that contains a sequence of lines, each of which is numbered (in order):

```
$ cat words.txt
1. something
2. something else
....
1000. yet something else
```

And you want to print a range of lines, you can use `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '50,100p' words.txt
50. abandonee
51. abandoner
52. abandonment
...
98. abbacomes
99. abbacy
100. Abbadide
```

The `-n` says "don't print lines by default", the `50,100p` means "for lines 50-100, print the line".

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you so much. I used your second command which works fine but I'm wondering whether this also prints in Alphabetical order by default or if we need additional commands for that.

Comment: I built my sample using words from a dictionary, so they're in alphabetical order, but that has no affect on the output.  My command just prints line 50-100, independent of what's on the line.